# Bayesian output vs frequentist. Which should I rely on? MLM/ RE HLM

Tags: r, multilevel-analysis, lme4-nlme, hierarchical-bayesian

I have 2 questions.

1)My Bayesian output is providing some trouble.  I have data that will vary across 5 countries.  This means my group level has a small n of 5.  This results in my data hovering around the mean and provides different results from the frequentist.

When trying to decide how to interpret the data and ultimately make a decision, should I explain why the data are hovering around the mean, interpret the effects, but then rely mainly on the frequentist results?

2)Also, I am getting mixed answers on what a significant intercept means for an HLM model.  Can anyone help?

bayesian:

```
             Mean     SD 
Intercept   2.32905 2.5980 
var1.2     -0.23847 2.6300 
var1.3     -0.51286 2.6157 
cor         1.59379 0.7850       
var1.2:cor -0.04556 0.7991 
var1.3:cor -0.03126 0.7846
```

here it seems like there is no credible difference between the levels of var.  cor is credible but the interaction between levels of var are not? How would I interpret the intercept?  That should be var1.1 on y.

frequentist:

```
    mod1 <- lmer(y ~ var:cor + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + x6 + 
      ( var | country), data=dat)

    Random effects:
    Groups   Name            Variance Std.Dev. Corr     
    country (Intercept)      0.09393  0.3065            
             var1.2          0.06549  0.2559   0.64     
             var1.3          0.08091  0.2845   1.00 0.58
 Residual                    4.37552  2.0918            
 Number of obs: 5278, groups:  country, 5

Fixed effects:
               Estimate Std. Error         df  t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)    7.291e+00  7.396e-01  6.000e+00   9.859 4.25e-05 *** 
    var1.2    -9.489e-01  6.420e-01  6.000e+00  -1.478   0.1867    
    var1.3    -1.883e+00  7.229e-01  5.000e+00  -2.605   0.0445 *  
    cor        3.056e-01  1.986e-01  6.000e+00   1.539   0.1782        
    var1.2:cor 1.385e-01  1.867e-01  8.000e+00   0.742   0.4802    
    var1:3:cor 3.298e-01  2.100e-01  7.000e+00   1.570   0.1635
```

here it seems the only significant level of var is var1.3.  here cor is not significant.  and neither are the interactions with var?  How would I interpret the intercept?  That should be var1.1 on y.

And again, which should I rely on?

Comment: Note that the p values for fixed factor effects in the `lmer()` output are for differences of each level from whichever reference level you used. So `var1.3` is listed as (barely) significantly different from `var1.1`. My guess is that ANOVA wouldn't find a main effect for `var` if all 3 levels were considered together.

Comment: @EdM actually the anova returns var (all together) is significant, which is interesting.  of the 5 or 6 variables, it is the only one that is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since @mattbarstead answered question two so competently, I thought I should answer question one.

Your question is "should I trust my Bayesian or my Frequentist model" and the answer is "no."  You should only do one or the other, but never both.  This isn't because they could differ and there would be no objective way to solve your problem, but because they are not answering the same question in the first place.

A couple of qualifications about the two methods should be noted.  Frequentist methods are *ex ante* optimal.  That is to say, prior to picking up your data, there is no better way to analyze your data.  This optimality is understood that if you were to cover the sample space that, on average, the solution meets some set of optimality criteria, such as unbiasedness, consistency and so forth.    Bayesian methods are *ex post* optimal.  That is they only become optimal models after they have seen the data and the solutions are specifically unique to the sample seen.  There is no way to extract more information about the location of a parameter than a Bayesian method.  That said, the specific Bayesian result from one sample could be a poor solution when seen over the whole sample space, but the averaging rules of Frequentist methods mean using a Frequentist method could be a poor method for the sample that happened to be seen in the study.

The second is the nature of hypotheses.  Frequentist hypothesis must be binary.  The null here is the "no effect" hypothesis, that is in a broader form $\mu=k=0$.  This is treated as intrinsically true before it sees the data.  The data may reject this, but it is assumed true.  Bayesian hypotheses are combinatoric.  There is nothing similar to the hypothesis that $\mu=k$ because if your solution is in the real numbers then $\Pr(\mu=k)\equiv{0}$.  Just because zero is in the Bayesian credible interval does not mean that $\mu=k.$  It is just one of an infinite number of possible solutions.

You should be choosing a Frequentist method because you have an existential or true/false style question that needs to be answered.  This is especially true if you want to use the "no effect" hypothesis.  There is no real Bayesian equivalent to the "no effect" hypothesis.

You should choose the Bayesian method when you have multiple competing models of the world.  The Frequentist methodology has to jump to the Bayesian in order to do model selection through tools like the AIC or BIC, which are really stylized and constrained Bayesian summary statistics.  For any one Frequentist method, an infinite number of Bayesian models exists.  A t-test covers an unbelievably wide set of possible solutions that are different and distinct when constructed as a Bayesian problem.  The t-test just depends upon how the sample was collected, whereas the Bayesian posterior depends upon how the likelihood is constructed.  This implies that the Bayesian depends upon how you model the laws of the universe.  It is built on modeling.  The Frequentist is an algorithm based on the sampling rules.

The second case for using Bayesian methods is when real prior knowledge exists, such as prior research where there is at least partial information on the parameters.  If real prior knowledge exists then Frequentist methods are statistically inadmissible.  The Bayesian solution will always stochastically dominate the Frequentist in that case.

You need to think through the question of "what do I need to know?"  Do you need to know if these variables really do not impact the dependent variable?  Do you need to discover which of many possible models of the world is the closest to the model nature uses to generate the data?  The former is Frequentist, the later, Bayesian.  The former permits you to make deductive statements, the latter is not considering the models you did not test and so is an incomplete form of reasoning.  Because there could be models you did not think of, the Bayesian posterior is incomplete.  All possible models, except the alternative hypothesis, exist in the null by its very construction.

Your construction of the Bayesian model looks like a Frequentist construction.  Have you considered all possible ways to combine the variables, including dropping variables?

Comment: Thanks so much for this thoughtful reply. I was starting to see what you're saying as I was trying to interpret the results.  I am using Bayesian methods here because I was interested to see if the model was correct.  The small M (group level) was causing the results to hover around the mean.  When more cases are added at the second level, it is (naturally) given more space to vary, and looks as one would expect.  For both small and larger M models, the Gelman and the Geweke, etc confirm convergence. /1

Comment: The frequentist method, on the other hand,  assumes the model is correct.  I was thinking of using the frequentist results to answer the hypothesis questions.  Yes, I dropped variables-there is almost no difference in the outcome in either case.  If I drop too many the model degrades./2

Answer (score 3):

I think I can be more useful RE: #2 as a frequentist who, though appreciative of the logic, is only minimally trained in Bayesian techniques.

The reason for the various answers regarding the interpretation of a grand intercept in a multilevel model is that it depends entirely on what 0 represents on your level 1 and level 2 covariates. Centering decisions heavily influence the interpretation of intercepts in regression models in general and especially so in HLM/MLM models. See this [brief treatment](http://www.ssicentral.com/hlm/techdocs/Centering.pdf) for some additional guidance that may be helpful. It was written for HLM users but perhaps is also applicable in this instance.

In general, reasoning through the interpretation of an intercept in multilevel models can be one of the trickiest components of HLM/MLM.

Hope that helps and good luck.